# What is the grammatical form for the ungrammatical 昨日雨が降ったそうだ?

Tags: grammar

Consider the situation in which when I left my house in the morning for working, I found the street was wet. I think the following expression is ungrammatical.

> 昨日雨が降ったそうだ。

Because ～そうだ (conjecture) must represent event that will happen in the future or represent the current state of something or someone.

> 昨日雨が降りそうだった。

does not make sense as well, right?

## Question

So what is the correct expression to say the following?

> There might be raining yesterday.

Comment: But 昨日雨が降ったそうだ means "[someone] told me that it rained yesterday."

Comment: @oals: I am not talking about "hearsay".

Comment: "There might be raining yesterday" does not make much sense. Did you mean to say "It might have  been raining yesterday"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [～ようだ](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%A7%98%E3%81%A0) that means "seeming to be" or "appearing to be":

> 昨日雨が降った**ようだ**。
>
> It seems that it rained yesterday.

---

By the way, 昨日雨が降りそうだった。 is still a valid sentence which means "it seemed likely to rain yesterday."

This is valid because "雨が降りそう" was a conjecture about future or present at the time it was made.